# DOM, use a variable font-size

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to manipulate font-size with a variable, but it is not working. Can anybody see what is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/yRLN3/2/

```
<div id = "letter">
    <span>A</span>
     <span>l</span>
     <span>p</span>
     <span>h</span>
     <span>a</span>
     <span>b</span>
     <span>e</span>
     <span>t</span>
     <div>

var list = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var size = 20;
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    size+=5;
    list[i].style.fontSize = "sizepx";
    };
alert(list.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made Typing mistake

list[i].style.fontSize = size + "px";

Size is a variable which is int ,but your code took it String as it had quotes.

Answer (score 7):

A small typo:

```
list[i].style.fontSize = size + "px";
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/yRLN3/5/)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/yRLN3/2/7

```
list[i].style.fontSize = size + "px";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a correct fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yRLN3/3/

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var size = 20;
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    size+=5;
    list[i].style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
alert(list.length);
```